# In JQuery UI, How to know the current status ( expanded or collapsed ) of the Accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using JQuery accordion. On click, I want to know the current status of it. How can I know it?

Comment: The answers are good, Butm , one problem that I am facing is that ui-state-active , already, has background Image and now, I want to load a small icon on right side. ( I already have icon on left side ). So, I canonot use ui-state-active for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery sets a class on the active/opened accordion: "ui-state-active" vs. ".ui-state-default" (these are the classes on the Accordion demo on Jquery website: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

Edit: You can of course then check each accordion to see if it has the active vs. default class

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
if($('#my_accordion h3′).hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
// accordion is open
}
else {
// accordion is closed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the `changestart` (before a change) and `change` (after a change) event for the accordion, the callback passes the values `event` and `ui`.  `ui` has properties `newHeader`, `oldHeader`, `newContent`, and `oldContent` containing the values of the new and old headers and contents that you can use to see what was and now is expanded.  These events will happen on whatever your trigger event is for a change (click, mouseover, etc.)